# Bold tag breaking the divs?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I really cant understand this issue, and apparently neither the theme producer:

https://www.busstop.it/novita/rel-1005-di-busstop/

Look at the last paragraph, the point **4)** on the list is split into 4 columns just because it has some **bold** text in it. What could be the cause of this??

We only replicated it when the line is more than one and has bold text insdie. On single lines it is supposed to happen but it is not visible.

Comment: don't post link  ... post code

Comment: Please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/, then [ask] and  [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: _“What could be the cause of this?”_ - the fact that the parent container is a `flex` element, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code because of your "tatsu-column" name class conflict your CSS. That you can see below:

```
.tatsu-column {
    display: flex;
}
```

**you have 2 options to correct your CSS without conflict.**

**1)**

```
.tatsu-column {
    display: block;
}
```

**Or**

**2)** **change your tatsu-column class style to :**

```
.tatsu-column {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```